# SRA can not have such operands?

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl

I have coded an algorithm in VHDL but I have this message that I don't understand "sra/sla can not have such operands in this context.". Any help please?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.conv_std_logic_vector;

entity hsl2rgb is
    generic(
        constant hue : integer := 85;
        constant sat : integer := 127
    );
    port(
        lum    : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        ored   : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        ogreen : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
        oblue  : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of hsl2rgb is
begin

    process(lum)
        variable v : integer;
        variable m : integer;
        variable sextant : integer;
        variable fract : integer;
        variable vsf : integer;
        variable mid1 : integer;
        variable mid2 : integer;
        variable lumx : integer;
    begin
        lumx := to_integer(unsigned(lum));
        if (lumx < 127) then
            v := (lumx * (256 + sat)) sra 8;
        else
            v := (((lumx + sat) sla 8) - lumx * sat) sla 8;
        end if;

        if (v <= 0) then
            ored <= (others => '0');
            ogreen <= (others => '0');
            oblue <= (others => '0');
        else
            m := (2 * lumx) - v;
            sextant := (hue * 6) sra 8;
            fract := (hue * 6) - (sextant sla 8);
            vsf := (fract * (v - m)) sra 8;
            mid1 := m + vsf;
            mid2 := v - vsf;

            case sextant is
                when 0 =>
                    ored <= conv_std_logic_vector(v, 6);
                    ogreen <= conv_std_logic_vector(mid1, 6);
                    oblue <= conv_std_logic_vector(m, 6);
                when 1 =>
                    ored <= conv_std_logic_vector(mid2, 6);
                    ogreen <= conv_std_logic_vector(v, 6);
                    oblue <= conv_std_logic_vector(m, 6);
                when 2 =>
                    ored <= conv_std_logic_vector(m, 6);
                    ogreen <= conv_std_logic_vector(v, 6);
                    oblue <= conv_std_logic_vector(mid1, 6);
                when 3 =>
                    ored <= conv_std_logic_vector(m, 6);
                    ogreen <= conv_std_logic_vector(mid2, 6);
                    oblue <= conv_std_logic_vector(v, 6);
                when 4 =>
                    ored <= conv_std_logic_vector(mid1, 6);
                    ogreen <= conv_std_logic_vector(m, 6);
                    oblue <= conv_std_logic_vector(v, 6);
                when 5 =>
                    ored <= conv_std_logic_vector(v, 6);
                    ogreen <= conv_std_logic_vector(m, 6);
                    oblue <= conv_std_logic_vector(mid2, 6);
                when others =>
                    ored <= (others => '0');
                    ogreen <= (others => '0');
                    oblue <= (others => '0');
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With integers you'll have to use `*` and `/` operators.  If they have constant powers-of-2 in the right places (ie on the right of the divide, either side of the multiply), the synthesiser will "do the right thing".

Or (as Charles noted) use `signed` or `unsigned` types from the `ieee.numeric_std library`.

BTW, why are you using `conv_std_logic_vector` when you have used `ieee.numeric_std`?

```
ored <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(mid1, 6));
```

should be what you require, then you can get rid of the nasty `ieee.std_logic_arith` library

(Aside: If you (or a future reader of this) are targeting an FPGA (and I accept you may not be but lots of people are these days:) you may find there is a need to pipeline that architecture somewhat if the target frequency is at all challenging.  At a brief eyeball-synthesis, there are upwards of a half-dozen adders, a couple of real multipliers and a few muxes - all in a single clock-cycle.  In particular this will preclude the use of the hard multipliers in all FPGAs I know of)

Comment: More specifically, you can use (x * 8) instead of (x sll 3).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have converted your std_logic_vector I/O into integers to perform math, but the sra/srl operands only work on 1D arrays of bit or boolean types.  You will probably have much better luck trying to work with signed or unsigned types (which are bit-vector representations of numbers) instead of mixing std_logic_vectors (which have no inherent numeric value) and integers (which have no bit-vector representation).